# Why can't I hook on html5 video play event?

Tags: meteor, html5-video

I am using an HTML5 video tag with videoJS (last stable release, 4.12). I have no trouble to get the `loadedmetadata` event but for some reason I probably missed, I can't hook using the "meteor way" on the video object `play` event.

My template events code:

```
Template.Player.events({
  'loadedmetadata #video_player':function (e,t) {
    console.log(e.target); //working fine
    },
  'play #video_player':function(e,t){
    console.log("play!");//now it works
  }
});
```

I am debugging on Chrome but i guess it is not browser related.

---

**edit:**

It appears that it works when I don't use id or class selectors. Since I have only one video tag on my template, I can catch the `play` event by doing this:

```
Template.Player.events({
  'play video':function(e,t){
    console.log("play!");//not working
  }
});
```

I still don't buy the fact that meteor can't handle that. If so, why? What is the difference between `loadedmetadata` and `play` events that allows the first to use an `id` selector when the latter can't?

> play triggers only when playback is resumed, playing triggers every
>   time playback starts.

@Oskar, you are right when I look at the documentation. However, in my case, `play` triggers both when starting a video and when resuming it after a pause.

Answer (score 0):

First off, make sure you're using the correct event - `play` triggers only when playback is resumed, `playing` triggers every time playback starts.

Looking at the [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/eventmaps), these are the events that are "officially" supported:

> Event types and their uses include:
>
> **click**
>   Mouse click on any element, including a link, button, form control, or div. Use preventDefault() to prevent a clicked link from being followed. Some ways of activating an element from the keyboard also fire click.
>
> **dblclick**
>   Double-click.
>
> **focus, blur**
>   A text input field or other form control gains or loses focus. You can make any element focusable by giving it a tabindex property. Browsers differ on whether links, checkboxes, and radio buttons are natively focusable. These events do not bubble.
>
> **change**
>   A checkbox or radio button changes state. For text fields, use blur or key events to respond to changes.
>
> **mouseenter, mouseleave**
>   The pointer enters or leaves the bounds of an element. These events do not bubble.
>
> **mousedown, mouseup**
>   The mouse button is newly down or up.
>
> **keydown, keypress, keyup**
>   The user presses a keyboard key.  keypress is most useful for catching typing in text fields, while keydown and keyup can be used for arrow keys or modifier keys.
>
> **Other DOM events are available as well, but for the events above, Meteor has taken some care to ensure that they work uniformly in all browsers.**

Comment: I tried `playing` as well with the same result. And considering the "official" support of this set of event, it does not mean that `play` is not supported (when `loadedmetadata`  would be). Actually, it would be surprising that a plateform like Meteor can't deal with it.